# Finer topology with some properties

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a nonempty set and define two topologies on $X$ say $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$, such that $\tau_1$ is finer than $\tau_2$, that is, $\tau_2\subset\tau_1.$ I want to see what are the properties that will be preserved. I mean, Assume, $(X,\tau_1)$ is : compact, connected, second countable, first countable, regular, and completely regular. Then, $(X,\tau_2)$  so dose. Is that right?

> Also, What are other properties that be preserved?

Comment: Second countable, first countable, completely regular or regular, not necessarily. For instance, the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R$ is second countable and completely regular, but the cofinite topology is neither first countable nor regular.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path, Thank you. how about the rest?

Comment: You are asking $7$ questions in one go, with no indication of any work on your part and with the seventh question completely open ended. Your question is also confused: you seem to be asking whether properties are preserved in the passage from $\tau_1$ to $\tau_2$, i.e., are preserved by making the topology coarser.

Comment: Open open cover of $(X,\tau_2)$ is an open cover of $(X,\tau_1),$ so if $(X,\tau_1)$ is compact, then $(X,\tau_2)$ is compact, Hausdorff works the other way: if $(X,\tau_2)$ is Hausdorff, then so is $(X,\tau_1).$.

Comment: Why are people helping with this badly phrased attempt to get free answers to some kind of multiple choice question?

Comment: $\tau_2\subseteq\tau_1$ is equivalent to saying the identity function $(X,\tau_1)\to(X,\tau_2)$ is continuous. This lets you deduce properties. Like, if $(X,\tau_1)$ is connected, the so is $(X,\tau_2).$

Comment: @RobArthan. This is not a homework assignment or anything else. I omitted the details since they are obvious but I was incorrect for the first and second countable.

Comment: Rob  is technically correct that this is still both vague and shows no work, however. @00GB

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Thank you this makes life easier better than writing details.

Comment: If the details are obvious, why are you asking the question? Connectedness is preserved under making the topology coarser but not always under making it finer: I have no idea from your confused question which of these facts you were concerned with.

Comment: @RobArthan, Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$:

All: Compactness, connectedness and second countability, first countability, regularity or complete regularity can all be missing from $\tau_2$, even when $\tau_1$ has them and is metrisable. Zero-dimensionality too, BTW.

Making a topology finer kills a lot of things.. Only obvious things like "disconnectedness", Hausdorff (and $T_0,T_1$) are preserved. Any property that can be witnessed from open subsets of $\tau_1$ alone..

If the finer topology is compact, or connected, so is the coarser one too. This is because these properties become "easier" with fewer open sets.

Answer (score 1):

If $(X,\tau_1)$ is completely regular, regular, and also zero dimension, then $(X,\tau_2)$  need not to have these properties. Since taking $\tau_1$ to be discrete topology. So,  $(X,\tau_1)$ is completely regular, regular, and also zero dimension but choose your favorite topology that does not have these.